# CircuiTikz: Inverter vs buffer logic gate dimensions

Tags: circuitikz

While running through the [CircuiTikz Documentation](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) I found that the buffer logic gate is not listed among the logic gates (§ 4.5). It is only listed among the amplifiers (§ 4.6). The problem i encountered is that the triangle of the inverter logic gate produced with CircuiTikz is a little different from the triangle of the buffer logic gate. However they should be exactly the same, according to bibliography. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to solve this?

**Input**

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[american not port] (mynot) {};
\draw (mynot.in) node[anchor=east] {$x$};
\draw (mynot.out) node[anchor=west] {$F$};
\end{circuitikz} \\

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[buffer] (mybuffer) {};
\draw (mybuffer.in) node[anchor=east] {$x$};
\draw (mybuffer.out) node[anchor=west] {$F$};
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: CircuiTikz Buffer vs Inverter as it is]

**Buffer and Inverter according to bibliography**

[image: CircuiTikz Buffer vs Inverter as it is supposed to be]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default height and width of a `buffer` this way:

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/height/.initial=0.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/width/.initial=0.9}
```

These values make the triangles the same.

[image: buffer]

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/height/.initial=0.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/buffer/width/.initial=0.9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[american not port] (mynot) {};
        \draw (mynot.in) node[anchor=east] {$x$};
        \draw (mynot.out) node[anchor=west] {$F$};
    \end{circuitikz} \\

    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) node[buffer] (mybuffer) {};
        \draw (mybuffer.in) node[anchor=east] {$x$};
        \draw (mybuffer.out) node[anchor=west] {$F$};
    \end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```